# search multiple keywords python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I improve my code to search using a list of keywords in a specific column of a dataframe and return those rows that contains the value. the current code only accepts two keywords!

```
contain_values = df[df['tweet'].str.contains('free','news')]
contain_values.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently only returns tweets that contain `'free'` and ignores `'news'`. Let’s test it:

```
>>> df
          tweet
0    free stuff
1  newsnewsnews
2   hello world
3 another tweet
>>> df[df['tweet'].str.contains('free', 'news')]
        tweet
0  free stuff
```

See the [documentation for .str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html): you can either pass a word, or a [regular expression](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.9/library/re). This will work:

```
df[df['tweet'].str.contains('free|news|hello')]
```

Here I’ve added a 3rd keyword, and now the first 3 elements of my dataframe are returned:

```
          tweet
0    free stuff
1  newsnewsnews
2   hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

`Series.str.contains` takes a regular expression, per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). Either construct a regular expression with your values or use a for-loop to check multiple elements one-by-one and then aggregate back.

Thus (for the regular expression):

```
regex = '|'.join(['free', 'news'])
df['tweet'].str.contains(regex, case=False, na=False)
```

Note that you cannot pass a list directly to `Series.str.contains`, it'll raise an error. You also probably want to pass `case=False` and `na=False` to make the regular expressions case-insensitive and pass `False` if you have `NaN` somewhere in your tweet columns (like for a no-comment retweet).